# In google maps api what does this address mean

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view

I develop in Android Google street view api and came across this strange address:

> 8121 1/2 Stenton Ave Philadelphia, PA 19150 USA

What is the "1/2" used for?

[Google maps link](https://www.google.se/maps/place/8121+1%2F2+Stenton+Ave,+Philadelphia,+PA+19150,+USA/@40.0674548,-75.1792381,19z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x89c6b9934599a4fb:0x51cc3906cce06f26!2s8121+1%2F2+Stenton+Ave,+Philadelphia,+PA+19150,+USA!3b1!8m2!3d40.0674538!4d-75.1786909!3m4!1s0x89c6b9934599a4fb:0x51cc3906cce06f26!8m2!3d40.0674538!4d-75.1786909)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, addresses with "1/2" can be a small apartment (flat) or other division,  like an office, in the main building.

I've never seen a "1/3" or "15/64" or anything except "1/2".

Comment: Thanks was looking [here](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats/united_states/) for some Explan. about this but nothing.

Comment: When the Mailman deliver mail what does the "1/2" really do? I mean an address is "one" address not half an address, what is the logic

Comment: That web page looks incomplete. As you've found US addresses can have a "1/2" or they can also have suite numbers like "Suite 233" or "ste 233" as well as letters like "A" or "F".

Comment: The apartment or small office has a mailbox labeled "1234 1/2 Whatever St." and the mailman drops letters into it.

Comment: Most likely, the building was originally "1234 Whatever St." and they added a small apartment in the rear. Since 1236 is probably taken, they just add "1/2" or "A" to show that the small apartment is not 1234 and not 1236.

Comment: Can i be now like "1234 1/3 Whatever St." or "1234 1/4 Whatever St."

Comment: I've never seen a "1/3" or "15/64" or anything except "1/2".

Comment: You should add that to your Answer - "Most likely, the building was originally "1234 Whatever St." and they added a small apar"

Comment: Knowing this much one would have thought that they could add a letter like "1234 F Whatever St."